# Could we produce an expression for such a function?

Tags: functions, definition

I am looking for a function that takes $n$ parameters $ x_1, x_2, ... x_n $, such that, if and only if 
any $i$th parameters are equal, then the outputs are equal. Mathematicaly, 
$$ f:R^n \rightarrow R,\ \forall (i = 1,2,...n)  ({x_i}_1={x_i}_2 \leftrightarrow  f(...{x_i}_1...)=f(...{x_i}_2...)) $$

Could we generalize this idea for $n$ parameters? I am looking for a mathematical expression of this function, only satisfying this property. Any operator is plausible as long as it is in mathematical concept (logical, modula , arithmetic etc.).

Comment: This is just $n$ dimensional injectivity.

Comment: Peter Foreman - No I don't think it is. He didn't say $$\left(\forall i\in(0,..,n),x_{i_1}=x_{i_2}\right)\Leftrightarrow\left(f(..x_{i_1}..)=f(..x_{i_2}..)\right)$$

He said $$\forall i\in(0,..,n),\left(x_{i_1}=x_{i_2}\Leftrightarrow f(..x_{i_1}..)=f(..x_{i_2}..)\right)$$
which is quite different.

Comment: One thing to note is that $$f(x_1,..,x_n)-f(y_1,..,y_n)=\lambda(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)..(x_n-y_n)$$(with $\lambda\neq0$) is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for $f$ in order to satisfy this property.

Now, is there any such function, I don't know.